# HitHighlight only for current Range

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, netoffice

I am using the following code to find some strings in my document:

```
Application application = Addin.Application;
Document document = application.ActiveDocument;
Range rng = document.Content;

rng.Find.ClearFormatting();
rng.Find.Forward = true;
rng.Find.Text = findText;

while (rng.Find.Execute() && rng.Find.Found)
{
    //here: rng.Text == findText
    //however rng.Find.HitHighlight(findText, WdColor.wdColorAqua);
    //highlights all occurrences in the document, not in the current range
}
```

as the comments in the code state, I'd expect `rng.Find.HitHighlight(findText, WdColor.wdColorAqua);` to only work on the current range but instead it executes on the whole document.

Interestingly if I start from a different range this works as I would expect... ie.

```
Range rng = document.Content.Paragraphs.First.Range;
rng.Find.HitHighlight("video", WdColor.wdColorAqua);
```

will only `HitHighlight` the `findText` in the first paragraph.

This is inconsistent... Any ideas on how to perform `HitHighlight` only on the range selected using `Find`?

**NOTE:** I tried this in a NetOffice addin and I get the same behavior.

Comment: But didn't you set the range as the entire document `Range rng = document.Content;`?

Comment: @Magnetron - I did but then `rng.Find.Execute()` set the range to an instance found, hence the comment `//here: rng.Text == findText` moreover in debug I can see `rng.Start` and `rng.End` move along to each found instance at every iteration.

Comment: I have also tried to use a new range created using the old one like this `Addin.Application.ActiveDocument.Range(rng.Start, rng.End).Find.HitHighlight("video", WdColor.wdColorAqua);` but `HitHighlight` still runs on the whole document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the [`Find.HitHighlight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.find.hithighlight) method is not intended to be used at the same time as `Find.Execute`. It seems to use whatever range was present when you call `Execute`. If you don't call execute, it uses the current range.

> **Remarks**
>
> The HitHighlight method applies primarily to search highlighting in Office Outlook when Word is specified as the email editor. However, you can use this method on documents inside Word if you want to highlight found text. Otherwise, use the Execute method.

I suspect there is no way to do this except by iterating through each paragraph, which you already know about.

I realize this is not a complete answer but VSTO is not a popular tag and this may be the best you are going to get. Most questions go completely unanswered, and often without comments as well.